# Make links contained in jQuery DOMWindow open in same window

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

I have a jQuery DOMWindow that's loaded with AJAX on one of my web pages. For various technical reasons, I have to use AJAX instead of iFrames to load the content. Currently, any hyperlinks located inside the DOMWindow cause the browser to reload a new page instead of simply opening the content inside the same DOMWindow.

Is there any way to make a hyperlink open inside the same DOMWindow. I have tried including `target="_self"` in the hyperlink code.

This is the configuration of my jQuery DOMWindow:

```
                $('.AjaxDOMWindow').openDOMWindow({
                anchoredClassName:'DOMWindow',
                draggable: 1,
                eventType:'click',
                height:500,
                loader:1,
                loaderHeight:16,
                loaderImagePath:'/js/jquery/DOMWindow/animationProcessing.gif',
                loaderWidth:17,
                positionLeft:0,
                positionTop:0,
                positionType:'centered',
                width:700,
                windowHTTPType:'get',
                windowSource:'ajax'
            });
```

This is the hyperlink in question:

```
<a href="/foo/foo/edit_map_pin_more.htm?mAddressBox0=FALSE&width=800&height=600&mPin_ID=5"><b>View More Icons</b></a>
```

Comment: if u dont add a target attribute it should open in same window

Comment: @3nigma, I edited the question to include the HTML code for the hyperlink. Any idea why it might be causing the browser to open an entirely new parent page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is that there's *no* window in the true sense. There's just a `div` inside the main page acting as DOMWindow. So any links in that div will surely refresh the main doc.

Keep everything the same and **add** this:

```
$('.AjaxDOMWindow a').live("click", function(){
    $(this).openDOMWindow({
        anchoredClassName:'DOMWindow',
        draggable: 1,
        eventType:'click',
        height:500,
        loader:1,
        loaderHeight:16,
        loaderImagePath:'/js/jquery/DOMWindow/animationProcessing.gif',
        loaderWidth:17,
        positionLeft:0,
        positionTop:0,
        positionType:'centered',
        width:700,
        windowHTTPType:'get',
        windowSource:'ajax'
    });
});
```

Comment: since `.live` is deprecated what would be the proper substitute?

Comment: You'll have to use the new `on()` method. More about it here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

I think call to Dom window plugin is not binded to anchor tag.
I Placed above function in document.ready function which binds after dom has loaded and it worked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(AjaxDOMWindow ).openDOMWindow({         
        anchoredClassName:'DOMWindow',
        draggable: 1,
        eventType:'click',
        height:500,
        loader:1,
        loaderHeight:16,  
        loaderImagePath:'/js/jquery/DOMWindow/animationProcessing.gif', 
        loaderWidth:17,
        positionLeft:0,
        positionTop:0,
        positionType:'centered',
        width:700,
        windowHTTPType:'get',
        windowSource:'ajax'
    });
});
```